# Reducing time of populating a JavaFX TableView from a database using JPA/EclipseLink

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, optimization, javafx

I have a `JavaFX` `TableView` that I populate using a `JPQL` `Query` with `EclipseLink` that gets data from `Client` table in a `MySQL` `database`. the more data is stored in `Client` table the longer it takes to populate the table, which create that feeling of lagging for the user. and it became really annoying giving that it takes `4 seconds` to load `1600 records`, I created a `Thread` to load the GUI before fetching records but it makes no difference. do you guys have any ideas to optimize my code ? here it is :

> Here is `initialize()` that starts the thread and then the fetching :

```
@Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        Thread refresh = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //Optilight.echo("showLoadingWindow()");
                        //FactureTemplateController.showLoadingWindow();
                        mouseRightClick();
                        refreshData();
                        //Optilight.echo("hideLoadingWindow()");
                        //FactureTemplateController.hideLoadingWindow();
                        return;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        refresh.setDaemon(true);
        refresh.start();


    }
```

> Fetching data :

```
public void refreshData(){
    em = Optilight.emf.createEntityManager();

            List<Client> lst = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Client c JOIN FETCH c.personne p ORDER BY c.codePersonne DESC").getResultList();


            data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

            for (Client client : lst) {

                data.add(new ClientFX(
                        client.getCodePersonne(), client.getPersonne().getNom(),
                        client.getPersonne().getPrenom(), client.getPersonne().getAdresse(),
                        client.getPersonne().getLocalite(), client.getPersonne().getCodePostale(),
                        client.getPersonne().getPays(), client.getPersonne().getGsm(),
                        client.getPersonne().getFax(), client.getPersonne().getFixe(),
                        client.getPersonne().getEmail(), client.getPersonne().getFirstConatct(),
                        client.getPersonne().getModified(), client.getRegimeMutuelle(), client.getNoMututelle(),
                        client.getConvention(), client.getTelConvention(), client.getTitre(),
                        client.getOrganismeSociale(), client.getCaisseSociale()
                ));

            }

            em.close();

            idClient.setStyle(" -fx-alignment: CENTER;");
            firstContactClient.setStyle("-fx-alignment: CENTER;");
            gsmClient.setStyle("-fx-alignment: CENTER;");
            ajoutePar.setStyle("-fx-alignment: CENTER;");

            tableClient.setItems(data);
            tableClient.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.UNCONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);

            idClient.setCellValueFactory(cell -> cell.getValue().getCodePersonneProperty());
            nomClient.setCellValueFactory(cell -> cell.getValue().getPersonneNom());
            prenomClient.setCellValueFactory(cell -> cell.getValue().getPersonnePrenom());
            adresseClient.setCellValueFactory(cell -> cell.getValue().getPersonneAdresse());
            gsmClient.setCellValueFactory(cell -> cell.getValue().getPersonneGsm());
            emailClient.setCellValueFactory(cell -> cell.getValue().getPersonneEmail());
            firstContactClient.setCellValueFactory(cell -> cell.getValue().getPersonneFirstContact());
            ajoutePar.setCellValueFactory(cell -> cell.getValue().getPersonneModified());
}
```

> ClientFX.java :

```
public class ClientFX  {

    private SimpleIntegerProperty codePersonne;
    private SimpleStringProperty regimeMutuelle;
    private SimpleStringProperty noMututelle;
    private SimpleStringProperty convention;
    private SimpleStringProperty telConvention;
    private SimpleStringProperty titre;
    private SimpleStringProperty organismeSociale;
    private SimpleStringProperty caisseSociale;
    private Personne personne;
    private List<Dossiermonture> dossiermontureList;


    public ClientFX() {
    }

    public ClientFX(Integer codePersonne) {
        this.codePersonne = new SimpleIntegerProperty(codePersonne);
    }

   public ClientFX(Integer codePersonne, String nom, String prenom, String adresse, String localite,
                    String codePostale, String pays, String gsm, String fax, String fixe, String email,
                    String firstConatct,String modified,String regimeMutuelle, String noMututelle, String convention,
                    String telConvention, String titre, String organismeSociale, String caisseSociale) {

        this.personne=new Personne(codePersonne, nom, prenom,adresse,
                                   localite,codePostale,pays,gsm,fax,
                                   fixe,email,firstConatct,modified);
        this.codePersonne = new SimpleIntegerProperty(codePersonne);
        this.regimeMutuelle = new SimpleStringProperty(regimeMutuelle);
        this.noMututelle=new SimpleStringProperty(noMututelle);
        this.convention=new SimpleStringProperty(convention);
        this.telConvention=new SimpleStringProperty(telConvention);
        this.titre=new SimpleStringProperty(titre);
        this.organismeSociale=new SimpleStringProperty(organismeSociale);
        this.caisseSociale=new SimpleStringProperty(caisseSociale);
    }


    public Integer getCodePersonne() {
        return codePersonne.get();
    }

     public SimpleIntegerProperty getCodePersonneProperty() {
        return codePersonne;
    }
    public void setCodePersonne(Integer codePersonne) {
        this.codePersonne = new SimpleIntegerProperty(codePersonne);
    }

    public String getRegimeMutuelle() {
        return regimeMutuelle.get();
    }

     public SimpleStringProperty getRegimeMutuelleProperty() {
        return regimeMutuelle;
    }

    public void setRegimeMutuelle(String regimeMutuelle) {
        this.regimeMutuelle = new SimpleStringProperty(regimeMutuelle);
    }

    public String getNoMututelle() {
        return noMututelle.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty getNoMututelleProperty() {
        return noMututelle;
    }

    public void setNoMututelle(String noMututelle) {
        this.noMututelle = new SimpleStringProperty(noMututelle);
    }

    public String getConvention() {
        return convention.get();
    }

      public SimpleStringProperty getConventionProperty() {
        return convention;
    }

    public void setConvention(String convention) {
        this.convention = new SimpleStringProperty(convention);
    }

    public String getTelConvention() {
        return telConvention.get();
    }

     public SimpleStringProperty getTelConventionProperty() {
        return telConvention;
    }

    public void setTelConvention(String telConvention) {
        this.telConvention = new SimpleStringProperty(telConvention);
    }

    public String getTitre() {
        return titre.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty getTitreProperty() {
        return titre;
    }

    public void setTitre(String titre) {
        this.titre = new SimpleStringProperty(titre);
    }

    public String getOrganismeSociale() {
        return organismeSociale.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty getOrganismeSocialeProperty() {
        return organismeSociale;
    }

    public void setOrganismeSociale(String organismeSociale) {
        this.organismeSociale = new SimpleStringProperty(organismeSociale);
    }

    public String getCaisseSociale() {
        return caisseSociale.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty getCaisseSocialeProperty() {
        return caisseSociale;
    }

    public void setCaisseSociale(String caisseSociale) {
        this.caisseSociale = new SimpleStringProperty(caisseSociale);
    }


    @XmlTransient
    public List<Dossiermonture> getDossiermontureList() {
        return dossiermontureList;
    }

    public void setDossiermontureList(List<Dossiermonture> dossiermontureList) {
        this.dossiermontureList = dossiermontureList;
    }

    public Personne getPersonne() {
        return personne;
    }

    public void setPersonne(Personne personne) {
        this.personne = personne;
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty getPersonneNom() {

        return new SimpleStringProperty(personne.getNom());

    }

    public SimpleStringProperty getPersonnePrenom() {

       return new SimpleStringProperty(personne.getPrenom());
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty getPersonneAdresse() {
       return new SimpleStringProperty(personne.getAdresse()); 
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty getPersonneLocalite() {
       return new SimpleStringProperty(personne.getLocalite()); 
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty getPersonneCodePostale() {
       return new SimpleStringProperty(personne.getCodePostale()); 
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty getPersonnePays() {
       return new SimpleStringProperty(personne.getPays()); 
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty getPersonneGsm() {
       return new SimpleStringProperty(personne.getGsm()); 
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty getPersonneFax() {
       return new SimpleStringProperty(personne.getFax()); 
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty getPersonneFixe() {
       return new SimpleStringProperty(personne.getFixe()); 
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty getPersonneEmail() {
       return new SimpleStringProperty(personne.getEmail()); 
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty getPersonneFirstContact() {
       return new SimpleStringProperty(personne.getFirstConatct()); 
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty getPersonneModified() {
       return new SimpleStringProperty(personne.getModified()); 
    }
```

> Personne.Java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "personne")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personne.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Personne p"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personne.findByCodePersonne", query = "SELECT p FROM Personne p WHERE p.codePersonne = :codePersonne"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personne.findByNom", query = "SELECT p FROM Personne p WHERE p.nom = :nom"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personne.findByPrenom", query = "SELECT p FROM Personne p WHERE p.prenom = :prenom"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personne.findByAdresse", query = "SELECT p FROM Personne p WHERE p.adresse = :adresse"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personne.findByLocalite", query = "SELECT p FROM Personne p WHERE p.localite = :localite"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personne.findByCodePostale", query = "SELECT p FROM Personne p WHERE p.codePostale = :codePostale"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personne.findByPays", query = "SELECT p FROM Personne p WHERE p.pays = :pays"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personne.findByGsm", query = "SELECT p FROM Personne p WHERE p.gsm = :gsm"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personne.findByFax", query = "SELECT p FROM Personne p WHERE p.fax = :fax"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personne.findByFixe", query = "SELECT p FROM Personne p WHERE p.fixe = :fixe"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personne.findByEmail", query = "SELECT p FROM Personne p WHERE p.email = :email"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personne.findByFirstConatct", query = "SELECT p FROM Personne p WHERE p.firstConatct = :firstConatct")})
public class Personne implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "codePersonne", nullable = false)
    private Integer codePersonne;
    @Column(name = "nom", length = 254)
    private String nom;
    @Column(name = "prenom", length = 254)
    private String prenom;
    @Column(name = "adresse", length = 254)
    private String adresse;
    @Column(name = "localite", length = 254)
    private String localite;
    @Column(name = "codePostale", length = 254)
    private String codePostale;
    @Column(name = "pays", length = 254)
    private String pays;
    @Column(name = "gsm", length = 254)
    private String gsm;
    @Column(name = "fax", length = 254)
    private String fax;
    @Column(name = "fixe", length = 254)
    private String fixe;
    @Column(name = "email", length = 254)
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "firstConatct", length = 254)
    private String firstConatct;
    @Column(name = "modified", length = 254)
    private String modified;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "personne")
    private Fournisseur fournisseur;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "personne")
    private Client client;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "personne")
    private Docteur docteur;



    public Personne() {
    }

    public Personne(Integer codePersonne) {
        this.codePersonne = codePersonne;
    }

    Personne(Integer codePersonne, String nom,
             String prenom, String adresse,
             String localite, String codePostale,
             String pays, String gsm, String fax,
             String fixe, String email,
             String firstConatct,String modified) {

        this.codePersonne = codePersonne;
        this.nom = AES.encrypt(nom);
        this.prenom = AES.encrypt(prenom);
        this.adresse = AES.encrypt(adresse);
        this.localite = AES.encrypt(localite);
        this.codePostale = AES.encrypt(codePostale);
        this.pays = AES.encrypt(pays);
        this.gsm = AES.encrypt(gsm);
        this.fax = AES.encrypt(fax);
        this.fixe = AES.encrypt(fixe);
        this.email = AES.encrypt(email);
        this.firstConatct = AES.encrypt(firstConatct);
        this.modified = AES.encrypt(modified);

    }
    public Integer getCodePersonne() {
        return codePersonne;
    }

    public void setCodePersonne(Integer codePersonne) {
        this.codePersonne = codePersonne;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return AES.decrypt(nom);
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = AES.encrypt(nom);
    }

    public String getPrenom() {
        return AES.decrypt(prenom);
    }

    public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
        this.prenom = AES.encrypt(prenom);
    }

    public String getAdresse() {
        return AES.decrypt(adresse);
    }

    public void setAdresse(String adresse) {
        this.adresse = AES.encrypt(adresse);
    }

    public String getLocalite() {
        return AES.decrypt(localite);
    }

    public void setLocalite(String localite) {
        this.localite = AES.encrypt(localite);
    }

    public String getCodePostale() {
        return AES.decrypt(codePostale);
    }

    public void setCodePostale(String codePostale) {
        this.codePostale = AES.encrypt(codePostale);
    }

    public String getPays() {
        return AES.decrypt(pays);
    }

    public void setPays(String pays) {
        this.pays = AES.encrypt(pays);
    }

    public String getGsm() {
        return AES.decrypt(gsm);
    }

    public void setGsm(String gsm) {
        this.gsm = AES.encrypt(gsm);
    }

    public String getFax() {
        return AES.decrypt(fax);
    }

    public void setFax(String fax) {
        this.fax = AES.encrypt(fax);
    }

    public String getFixe() {
        return AES.decrypt(fixe);
    }

    public void setFixe(String fixe) {
        this.fixe = AES.encrypt(fixe);
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return AES.decrypt(email);
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = AES.encrypt(email);
    }

    public String getFirstConatct() {
        return AES.decrypt(firstConatct);
    }

    public void setFirstConatct(String firstConatct) {
        this.firstConatct = AES.encrypt(firstConatct);
    }

    public String getModified() {
        return AES.decrypt(modified);
    }

    public void setModified(String modified) {
        this.modified = AES.encrypt(modified);
    }



    public Fournisseur getFournisseur() {
        return fournisseur;
    }

    public void setFournisseur(Fournisseur fournisseur) {
        this.fournisseur = fournisseur;
    }

    public Client getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public void setClient(Client client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return AES.decrypt(this.nom)+" "+AES.decrypt(this.prenom);
    }
     public SimpleStringProperty getFullNameProperty() {

        return new SimpleStringProperty(AES.decrypt(this.nom)+" "+AES.decrypt(this.prenom));
    }


    public boolean DateSet(){
    if (this.firstConatct!="") 
     return true;
    else 
     return false;
    }
    public boolean DateNull(){
    if (this.firstConatct!=null) 
     return true;
    else 
     return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (codePersonne != null ? codePersonne.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Personne)) {
            return false;
        }
        Personne other = (Personne) object;
        if ((this.codePersonne == null && other.codePersonne != null) || (this.codePersonne != null && !this.codePersonne.equals(other.codePersonne))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "samplefx.model.Personne[ codePersonne=" + codePersonne + " ]";
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty getPrenomProperty() {
        return new SimpleStringProperty(this.getNom());
    }

    public Docteur getDocteur() {
        return docteur;
    }

    public void setDocteur(Docteur docteur) {
        this.docteur = docteur;
    }

}
```

> `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for `Client` table :

```
client | CREATE TABLE `client` (
  `codePersonne` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `regimeMutuelle` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
  `noMututelle` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
  `convention` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
  `telConvention` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
  `titre` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
  `organismeSociale` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
  `caisseSociale` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`codePersonne`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Generalization_4` FOREIGN KEY (`codePersonne`) REFERENCES `personne` (`codePersonne`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

As you can see there is a generalization foreign key to `Personne` Table.

> `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for `Personne` table :

```
personne | CREATE TABLE `personne` (
  `codePersonne` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nom` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prenom` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
  `adresse` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
  `localite` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
  `codePostale` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pays` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gsm` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fax` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fixe` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
  `firstConatct` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` varchar(254) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`codePersonne`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1588 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

> `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%';` :

```
bulk_insert_buffer_size             | 8388608
innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size       | 134217728
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown | ON
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now         | OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct         | 25
innodb_buffer_pool_filename         | ib_buffer_pool
innodb_buffer_pool_instances        | 1
innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort       | OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup  | ON
innodb_buffer_pool_load_now         | OFF
innodb_buffer_pool_size             | 134217728
innodb_change_buffer_max_size       | 25
innodb_change_buffering             | all
innodb_log_buffer_size              | 16777216
innodb_sort_buffer_size             | 1048576
join_buffer_size                    | 262144
key_buffer_size                     | 8388608
myisam_sort_buffer_size             | 41943040
net_buffer_length                   | 16384
preload_buffer_size                 | 32768
read_buffer_size                    | 65536
read_rnd_buffer_size                | 262144
sort_buffer_size                    | 262144
sql_buffer_result                   | OFF
```

Comment: Create a `Task` for fetching info from database and use `Platform.runLater()` to update the `Table`.

Comment: I'd already done that, see the edited code !

Comment: The only thing your thread does is submit the entire process back to the fx application thread - there's no point whatsoever in using a background thread solely to call `Platform.runLater()`. You need to do the database work on the background thread, not on the fx application thread.

Comment: Perhaps you have a lot of indexes?  And small settings for certain caches?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%'`.

Comment: And... Using threads won't help if the contention is downstream of the `INSERTs`.  Also `LOAD DATA` is much faster than 1600 separate `INSERTs`.  How are you doing the inserting???

Comment: @RickJames I provided what you asked, the inserts are processed in refreshData() mentioned in the question, I iterate through Client objects list and then I pass their fields to a ClientFX constructor, then I add that ClientFX object to FXCollections.observableArrayList() which I use to populate the TableView, Please tell me more about how I could use LOAD DATA. Thank you

Comment: @RickJames I understood the question to be about querying the database and displaying the results in the UI. There are no `INSERT`s, just a `SELECT`. Did I misread this?

Comment: Maybe I am confused -- Which are you concerned about?  "to load 1600 records" _into the database table_ (via `INSERTs` or MySQL's `LOAD DATA` command) or _into the application_ (`SELECT`)?

Comment: `SELECT c FROM Client c JOIN FETCH c.personne p ORDER BY c.codePersonne DESC` -- strange syntax; are you sure that is correct?

Comment: @James_D If you read my question you would know that I'm not having a problem querying the database and displaying into a `TableView`, I think that's why you marked the question as a duplicate whereas it has no duplicate, the `INSERT`s are being processed in an `ObservableList<OfMyObject>` from a `list<OfMyObject>` that I filled via a `JPQL Query`. It's all stated in my question !, It's the long time unnatural time that it takes to fill the table that became my concern as the records get bigger.

Comment: @RickJames Yes my syntax is correct. I'm concerned about an optimized code, I don't have any problem about selecting data from the database nor about inserting into the TableView.

Comment: No.  I am sure that that use of `FETCH` is incorrect.  `FETCH FROM cursor ...` is one kind of statement; `SELECT ... FROM tbl1 JOIN tbl2 ...` is a different kind of statement.  I see no hint that the two can be combined into a single statement.  Can you point to an example of your syntax online?  (I can't help you 'optimize' it until I understand it.)

Comment: What "optimization" do you seek?  Faster inserts?  Faster selects?  Shorter Java code?

Comment: @RickJames the query is not the issue because the one I provided in my question was just an edit of my original query which is : `SELECT c FROM Client c ORDER BY c.codePersonne DESC` , I want faster inserts from `list<ClientFX>` to `ObservableList<ClientFX> data`.

Comment: @AmmarAkouri I have read your question quite carefully, several times. It says "... using a JPQL Query with EclipseLink that gets data from Client table in a MySQL database." Then you say: "the longer it takes to populate the table, which create that feeling of lagging for the user". Here I assume "table" means the JavaFX `TableView`, and by "lagging" you mean the UI  becomes unresponsive (or slow to respond). The solution to this is to execute the query in a background thread, and process the results of the query on the FX Application Thread when the query completes.

Comment: @AmmarAkouri Your code doesn't do this: it *explicitly* executes the query on the FX Application Thread, which means the FX Application Thread can't do anything else (such as responding to user input or rendering the UI) while the query executes. The linked question explains *exactly* how to do this. Please clarify if I have misunderstood your question: if I have, I think you need to explain exactly which code causes the UI to "lag" (and perhaps what you mean by that).

Comment: @RickJames This is JPQL, not SQL, maybe that is not clear. The language spec covering fetch joins is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_04/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_fetch_joins)

Comment: @James_D at first I didn't mention that I created a Thread that loads the GUI while waiting for the TableView to get populated. but I edited the question before it was marked as duplicated. and yes your assumptions are all right.

Comment: @AmmarAkouri But, as I stated in my very first comment, the code you have posted *does not execute the query in a background thread*. That is exactly why I linked a post that shows you how to do that (which you apparently have not read). If you actually execute the query in a background thread (instead of the threading code you have currently posted in the question, which doesn't do anything of the sort), does it fix the problem? Or did you simply not bother to try what I suggested?

Comment: And *I* was pointing out to RickJames that it was JPQL, as he seemed to think it was supposed to be SQL. I also provided a link that he had requested, for the syntax spec that indicated the syntax was correct. You didn't read that comment carefully (which seems to be a bit of a theme in this thread).

Comment: @James_D Yep my bad, I thought it was RickJames addressing me.

Comment: @James_D Actually I did read it and thank you so much ! , I'm working on it and hope it'll solve my problem :). Thank you !

Comment: Sorry if I added confusion.  I have zero experience in JPQL.  I think I need to bow out with one of my nasty statements:  "Oh no, yet another 3rd party software complicating the use of MySQL more than simplifying it."

Comment: @James_D can you please provide me Executors `Class` in the answer you provided for my question duplicate ?

Comment: @AmmarAkouri `java.util.concurrent.Executors`

Comment: It's weird NetBeans didn't suggest an import that's why I thought It was a non Java defined class. now it did. Thank you man